# Spring picks repository implementation which even doesn't implement the repository interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have two interfaces in different packages:

```
package com.domain1

@Repository //expect that Spring will generate a bean
public interface PersonRepository extends org.springframework.data.repository.Repository<Person, UUID> {}
```

---

```
package com.domain2

//just an interface
public interface PersonRepository extends org.springframework.data.repository.Repository<Person, UUID> {}

//implementation
@Component
public PersonRepositoryImpl implements com.domain2.PersonRepository {}
```

---

And I try to inject the first repository:

```
public class MyClass {
    @Autowired
    com.domain1.PersonRepository personRepository;
}
```

---

I expect that spring-data-jpa injects a repository from `domain1` package but, instead of it, `com.domain2.PersonRepositoryImpl` is injected (a component which doesn't implement `com.domain1.PersonRepository` interface).

I tried using qualifiers - doesn't help.

Is this a bug or feature? :)

P.S. Of course, if I change the interface name then everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It is a feature of course. Interfaces can not be instantiated, instead, their implementations are. Spring will look for all implementations of a particular interface, if it can identify a unique one, which is your case, it will use that implementation.

If you have more than one it will give you an exception saying that there are multiple candidates for the autowire, and it can't pick one independentely. In this case you have to use the `@Qualifer` to specify which implementation is that you want.

Comment: If I didn't have PersonRepositoryImpl then Spring would create a repository bean.

Comment: Yes because it will give you an implementation out of the box provided by spring itself.

Comment: I made an example more explicit. You can see that the picked implementation class does not implement the repository interface I want to inject.

Comment: If you change the name of the repository and try to inject the one without Impl what do you get?

Comment: Please see the last part of my question: "P.S. Of course, if I change the interface name then everything works as expected."